# Deserialize Json in C# - How to Handle null Return Values

Tags: c#, json

I am using the following code:

```
myObj jsonStream = ser.Deserialize<myObj>(jsonStream);
```

And all was working fine until the JSON that came back had a null value for one of the fields.  i.e.:

```
"name" : null
```

During the deserialization process, it's throwing an exception.  In my myObj, I have a member:

```
public string name;
```

How can I gracefully handle the odd null value coming back from my datasource using the System.Web.Script.Serialization assembly?  I tried:

```
public string name = "";
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: I can't gather from your question what the type of "ser" is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx)

```
public string? name;
```

Comment: oh, I didn't know. But I'd try :)

Comment: This is actually the right answer in that I had to allowable nullable.  It turns out the example I used was a string, but it was the int that needed to be int?.  I just used a string for my example.  So, don't do "string?" for the reasons that Jauco points out, but this is the answer to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply settings to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to tell it how to handle null values, in this case, and much more:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                    };
var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonString, settings);
```

Comment: Still be useful in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem lies somewhere else because the following code worked fine for me using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (it correctly handled the null without throwing any exception):

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string name;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = "{\"name\" : null}";
        var myObj = ser.Deserialize<MyObj>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(myObj.name);
    }
}
```